# Kafka "Topic/Schema" source control and continuous delivery

Tags: apache-kafka, version-control, confluent-schema-registry, continuous-delivery

I'm in a small team that is going to begin using Kafka. I'm looking for information regarding development. i.e. How do we keep "our schema" source controlled? i.e. we'd like to ensure that we keep our topics, schema registries consistent, and be able to add/modify topics and the avro schema registry as part of a repeatable deployment process.

It seems to make sense that a developer should be able stand up a docker environment that would deploy our specific topic/schema configuration to a temporary container that they can develop against.

I've not been able to locate any examples of how anyone approaches this.

Comment: this looks promising https://devshawn.com/blog/automating-kafka-topic-and-acl-mangement/

Comment: We use the Avro Maven Plugin + Confluent SchemaRegistry Plugin to compile/version the Java classes. But the general answer is that you would mostly just need an HTTP wrapper around registering the schemas to the registry. The main issue is that you might need more than one registry in-case you happen to push out a bad schema as part of a PR/test and you are unable to roll it back